# PyvMomi create new virtual machine

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere

I have a connection to a vsphere instance using pyvmomi. I can list virtual machines. However, I am looking for documentation about how to perform other tasks (e.g. copy a virtual machine, create a new virtual machine). Is there example code for tasks like this or API documentation that is relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this github project? https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples

Lots of samples are provided here, if you are looking for something not already provided by the project please open an issue on github and maybe someone from the community will provide it for you.

Comment: Yes. At the time I asked the question the community samples did not exist and the project was a few weeks old.